# Responsive CSS: Organizing images issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to layout my images so when a mobile device sees them they are divided into 2 columns, and when larger devices see them they are divided into 3 columns. Simple.

However, there is a problem. Each of my images have a caption, some are longer than others, and as a result (in mobile view) when the images go under each other in 2 columns, the images may leave a gap because the caption of the image above it is interfering with it (or something).

So it should look like this:
(where captn means caption)

```
[image]    [image]
[captn]    [captn]

[image]    [image]
[captn]    [captn]
```

However, it looks like this:

```
[image]    [image]
[captn]    [captn]

           [image]
           [captn]
[image]
[captn]
```

Because the caption for the first image is slightly longer.

The easy solution is to shorten the caption of the first image, but I was to keep the detail. Help would be much appreciated :)

My current code:

Part of HTML:

```
<ul id="pictures">
      <li>
        <a href="img/blocks.jpg">
          <img src="img/blocks.jpg" alt="" />
          <p>THIS IS A LONG, LONG, LONG, LONG, LONG, LONG MESSAGE.......</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="img/code.jpg">
          <img src="img/code.jpg" alt="" />
          <p>Beautiful code.</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="img/skier.jpg">
          <img src="img/skier.jpg" alt="" />
          <p>Ski jumper.</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="img/android.jpg">
          <img src="img/android.jpg" alt="" />
          <p>Android intelligence is powerful.</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="img/woodland.jpg">
          <img src="img/woodland.jpg" alt="" />
          <p>An adventurous woodland.</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Part of CSS:

```
/*IMAGE STYLING*/

#pictures {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#pictures li {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#pictures li a p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: white;
}
```

Part of responsive CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

/*TWO COLUMN LAYOUT*/

#primary {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#secondary {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
}



/*Picture page*/

#pictures li {
    width: 28.3333%
}

#pictures li:nth-child(4n) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! I managed to find a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you'd flip the responsive from what you're doing, so you design for the larger screens and handle the smaller screens responsively (max-width:480px rather than min-width:480px). Because you've done it in that way I'll assume you have to for some reason.

Add this to the main part of your css:

```
#pictures li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Then add this to the responsive part:

```
#pictures li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: none;
}
```

This just tells it to split every second one. Without the directive, the code isn't quite sure how to handle the longer text. Simple, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your problem. Due the varying size of captions, alignment issue can happen as you described early.

**what you can do is**

1. Wrap the image and caption in a div
2. Give some min-height to the div (css fix)
3. Or use this method (I recomment)

```js
equalheight = function(container) {

  var currentTallest = 0,
    currentRowStart = 0,
    rowDivs = new Array(),
    $el,
    topPosition = 0;
  $(container).each(function() {

    $el = $(this);
    $($el).height('auto')
    topPostion = $el.position().top;

    if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
      for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
        rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
      }
      rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
      currentRowStart = topPostion;
      currentTallest = $el.height();
      rowDivs.push($el);
    } else {
      rowDivs.push($el);
      currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
    }
    for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
      rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
    }
  });
}
$(window).resize(function() { //to work in resize
  equalheight('li');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  equalheight('li');
});
```

```css
/*IMAGE STYLING*/

#pictures {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#pictures li {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#pictures li a p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: white;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  /*TWO COLUMN LAYOUT*/
  #primary {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  #secondary {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
  }
  /*Picture page*/
  #pictures li {
    width: 28.3333%
  }
  #pictures li:nth-child(4n) {
    clear: left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="pictures">
  <li>
    <a href="img/blocks.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>THIS IS A LONG, LONG, LONG, LONG, LONG, LONG MESSAGE.......</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/code.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>Beautiful code.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/skier.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>Ski jumper.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/android.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>Android intelligence is powerful.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/woodland.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="" />
      <p>An adventurous woodland.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Disable js and try to run the code, alignment issue will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [Equal Height of Columns](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you will use three **Column** and instead of floating the list item float the whole list **ul** with equal width (**33.33%**), then this procedure might help you.

And if you need two column in mobile view then just change the **ul**'s width to **50%**, so now the third column is the problem, for that you can use **100%** width for that column, or by using some JavaScript technique you can equally divide the items of third column into other two columns. I don't remember that technique at the moment, but you can Google it, because I was founded that technique in Google.

**Check the below example.**

```js
/*You don't have to use these JQuery, it is for demo purpose only, it creates different color for each 'li' */


$(document).ready(function() {
    var randomColors = ["black","yellow","red","blue","orange","pink","red","blue","black"];
    $(".item").each(function(index) {
        var len = randomColors.length;
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
        $(this).css("backgroundColor",randomColors[randomNum]);
        //Removes color from array so it can't be used again
        randomColors.splice(randomNum, 1);
    });
});
```

```css
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.item {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.item span {
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold; 
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.item img {
    width: 100%;
}


@media (max-width: 768px;){
    .col {
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    .third-col {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="col">
    <li class="item-1 item">
        <span>Caption 1</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250/food/Dummy-Text/">
    </li>
    <li class="item-2 item">
        <span>Caption 2</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/Dummy-Text/">
    </li>
    <li class="item-3 item">
        <span>Caption 3</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports/Dummy-Text/">
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="col">
    <li class="item-4 item">
        <span>Caption 4</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/120/sports/Dummy-Text/">
    </li>
    <li class="item-5 item">
        <span>Caption 5</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/280/sports/Dummy-Text/">
    </li>
    <li class="item-6 item">
        <span>Caption 6</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/sports/Dummy-Text/">
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="col third-col">
    <li class="item-7 item">
        <span>Caption 7</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/190/sports/Dummy-Text/">
    </li>
    <li class="item-8 item">
        <span>Caption 8</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/sports/Dummy-Text/">
    </li>
    <li class="item-9 item">
        <span>Caption 9</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/210/sports/Dummy-Text/">
    </li>    
</ul>
```